# How to use Edit view in index view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3 programming. I have user records `(userid, username)` in index view. I want to edit one record.

I am able to edit the record in Edit view. But my requirement is to show popup (just a div having textboxes for relevant fields) on index view and update the data for selected record.
After editing & saving the record, it should be updated in database and in the list on index page should also be updated with the new values.

Is it possible to open/integrate the Edit view inside a div on Index view?  If yes, then please provide me the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to edit the records. Jquery and jqueryui libs will help you parse the records and invoke a jquery dialog. Then the dialog ok button should invoke a ajax request to update the record in database and on success should update the record on the view as well.

For each record have a edit link or button and bind it to a click action using jquery to a function. The click action function will read the record previous to the edit link item i.e the elements previous to $(this) where $this is edit link element. Then you need to have a placeholder div element on the page hidden. Format the data read by the event into this div into input format and make a dialog of this div using jqueryui.